# can you reset data made in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I made a really good save file in candy box 2 but I want to restart. can you reset candy box 2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to clear out your cookies and local storage in your browser for this domain.

Please refer to your browsers manual for more information. However, here are some links for the most dominant browsers:

https://superuser.com/questions/548096/how-can-i-clear-cookies-for-a-single-site

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored

http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/security/privacy/

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/19/clear-cache-cookies-for-specific-domain-in-internet-explorer-9/

Answer (score 0):

No matter what browser, you can start a new game and then, when you have enough, press "request a new feature to the developer" until it gives you the save button, and then press and save on the slot you want to replace, and now your game is restarted.

NOTE:

It works on computers, and I know this because I've tried it, but I'm not sure it works on other devices. I'm also not sure about whether it clears cookies or not, but there's a large chance it doesn't, so watch out.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to the save box in Candy Box 2 and save a copy onto a program. Then you go to http://web.archive.org/web/20140402131808/http://candybox2.net/ and it it will restart for you there. If you want to go back to your old game, just make sure you go to the save button and upload the old text.

Answer (score -2):

Restart you browser and you should be reset.